# Is there a way to delay a Spring AnimationSpec in Jetpack Compose Animation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose Animation, for `tween` AnimationSpec, we can have a delay

```
                val translationY by transition.animateFloat(
                    transitionSpec = {
                        tween(
                            delayMillis = 1000, // Delay here
                            durationMillis = 2000
                        )
                    },
                    label = ""
                ) { if (it) 0f else 180f }
```

However, for Spring AnimationSpec, we only have dampingRatio (0.25f shown below) and Stiffness (100f shown below). There's no way to add a `delay`.

```
                val translationY by transition.animateFloat(
                    transitionSpec = {
                        spring(0.25f, 100f)
                    },
                    label = ""
                ) { if (it) 0f else 180f }
```

How to add a delay for Animation using  Spring AnimationSpec?

Comment: Could you give me an example of a transition here? A simpler one, not like an  `updateTransition`? It actually helps to provide helper code to developers here so that they can focus on the main problem you see.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to add the bouncing effect to tween that quite similar to spring. Just use

```
easing = { OvershootInterpolator().getInterpolation(it) }
```

OvershootInterpolator comes from **android.view.animation** package.

You can provide a tension argument into OvershootInterpolator by its constructor to change bounciness.

Comment: what is that, where do you add it? `fun <T> spring(
    dampingRatio: Float = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
    stiffness: Float = Spring.StiffnessMedium,
    visibilityThreshold: T? = null
)`

Comment: @user924 use tween with easing

Comment: The question is how to add a delay to a Spring animation, not how to make a Tween animation with a delay look like Spring.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such possibility, but there is a workaround.

Use tween with elastic easing

```
tween(durationMillis = 2000, delayMillis = 1000, easing = EaseOutElastic)
```

There is a few predefined easing in androidx.compose.animation.core.EasingFunctionsKt file.
[Here](https://easings.net/) you can see the preview of their behavior.

Comment: The question is how to add a delay to a Spring animation, not how to make a Tween animation with a delay look like Spring

Comment: So the answer is: 'no way'. What are you going to do with such knowledge?

Comment: At least understand that there is no real solution at this time. I appreciate your workaround, but the important thing is that it is a workaround. And the solution will be available when it is added to the Spring Animation API